# WP JSON list all permalinks

Tags: permalinks, filters, json

**Scenario**

I'm considering writing a custom wp-json endpoint to list ALL permalinks for everyone post in my wordpress.

**Question**

Is it possible to do this with a rest query + filters? eg. [http://wpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[only-permalinks]](http://wpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter%5Bonly-permalinks%5D)

## Current Solution

I ended up writing a custom endpoint, code below:

*added to the bottom of functions.php*

```
function get_all_slugs() {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => "screen",
    ) );

    if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    $posts_data = array();

    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $id = $post->ID; 
        
        $posts_data[] = (object) array( 
            'id' => $id, 
            'slug' => $post->post_name, 
            //'title' => $post->post_title,
        );
    }

    return $posts_data;
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'row/v1', '/all-slugs', array( // /(?P<post_type>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_all_slugs',
    ) );
} );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this with a rest query + filters? eg.
>   http://wpsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[only-permalinks]

Yes, since 4.9.8 (see [#43874](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43874)) it's possible to render only fields needed with the `_fields` parameter.

### Examples

Render only the *permalinks*:

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=link

```
[ 
    {
        link: "https://example.com/foo/"
    },
    {
        link: "https://example.com/bar/"
    },
]
```

Render only the *post IDs* and *permalinks*:

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=id,link

```
[ 
    {
        id: 123,
        link: "https://example.com/foo/"
    },
    {
        id: 234,
        link: "https://example.com/bar/"
    },
]
```

Render only the *post IDs* and the *slugs*:

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=id,slug

```
[ 
    {
        id: 123,
        slug: "foo"
    },
    {
        id: 234,
        slug: "bar"
    },
]
```

### Fetching All Available Items

Currently we have to fetch all available items with paging, like:

```
https://example.comwp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=slug&per_page=100&page=1
https://example.comwp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=slug&per_page=100&page=2
...
```

where `per_page` is 10 by default and with maximum value of 100.

Fetching all items in a single request can result in fatal errors if the number of items exceeds the available resources.

The ticket [#43998](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43998) to allow unbound requests (something like `per_page=-1`) for logged in users, was closed as *wontfix* because it doesn't scale and has performance issues.

There's a ticket [#45140](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45140) to increase the upper bound for `per_page` to few hundreds.

Usually there's no need to display so many items in a user interface and there exists javascript techniques to handle the pagination.

If more is really needed then one could filter the rest query via `rest_{$post_type}_query` to override the maximum default value of `posts_per_page`, at the risk of fatal errors if available resources are exceeded.

Comment: This is great! Is there any way to bend the 100 posts per page max?

Comment: I updated the answer with some additional notes.Hope it helps @Jacksonkr

Comment: It seems like this method can not get all posts without pagination. Not that getting thousands of posts is a good idea, but the OP asks for *all*.

Comment: We don't know the use case, so we try to mention the downsides of it and the reason core doesn't allow unbound REST queries :) I can imagine if `per_page=-1` were allowed on all WP sites, it would be a dream for attackers. All methods currently needs  some kind of PHP plugin code to override the `per_page` limitation in REST. If this is a one time only export, one could also try something like: `wp post list --fields=ID,name --post_type=post --post_status=publish --format=json > export.json` in wp-cli to avoid timeout (I think one might e.g. need to increase PHP memory limit for larger cases).

Comment: Considering your point about attackers & resources I can see why the 100 limit exists. A new endpoint is definitely the way to go for the customization I need. I'm marking this as the answer as you you nailed the op. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a default endpoint to let you get *all* the posts and return *only* the permalinks.

You could use the `posts` endpoint to get large chunks of permalinks (I don't believe it will let you return all of them in a single request) and paginate the request. To get it to return only the permalinks you could use the `json_prepare_post` filter all of which is outlined as part of [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-wp-api-to-fetch-posts/) tutorial.

However, if you must have *all* the permalinks in a single return, the most efficient way of doing it would be to add a new endpoint as outlined [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/). In the callback function you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274853/7656220) but instead of `echo`ing the permalinks put them in an array, `json_encode()` the array, and then return it.

Since this could become a monster of a process with a lot of posts, I'd recommend using the [Transient API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to store the request(s) - whether you choose to paginate and use the `posts` endpoint or return everything with a custom endpoint.