# Accessing WordPress Functions get_permalink() in Vanilla PHP?

Tags: php, functions, permalinks

Simple question. I'm attempting to use `get_permalink()` in vanilla php but cannot access it. I have `include_once` all these "used" files:

- wp-settings.php
- wp-includes/load.php
- wp-includes/link-template.php
- wp-includes/rewrite.php
- wp-includes/functions.php

and 10 other files. How do I access `get_permalink()`?

Comment: There’s no such function as get_permalinks(). It’s get_permalink(). But why do you need this in vanilla PHP? It doesn’t make sense to use outside of WordPress, and isn’t designed to be.

Comment: I created a feature-rich search page on a client's website, she has a Wordpress install and wanted links to her blog posts, so to create those links dynamically for her ongoing recent posts I need access to the links, but Wordpress uses Apache rewrite to make those permalinks dynamically, so I came up with this workaround. I'm not a Wordpress expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out. This file loads Wordpress and makes functions accessible.

```
include_once("wp-load.php");
```

then was able to

```
$id = $rowa["ID"];  //from MySQL fetch array
$permalink = get_permalink(number_format($id));
```

Answer (score 0):

The [developer's reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) is a great place to start. You'll find `get_permalink` in `wp-includes/link-template.php`.

You might want to look into [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/) `wp post list --post__in=1 --field=url` should do the trick [as discussed in wp-cli issue#2727](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/2727#issuecomment-218135008)

Also, there's the [rest-api](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) to consider. The best solution for getting the permalink might be to just post/cURL a request to WordPress' rest-api to get the permalinks you want.

This question might be a good place to start: [WP JSON list all permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324327/wp-json-list-all-permalinks)

For example, you could do something like the following:
`curl https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/<id>` or `curl https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/<id>`

& then find the `guid` / permalink from there.